# Multi-thread C# queue in .Net 4

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm developing a simple crawler for web pages. I've searched an found a lot of solutions for implementing multi-threaded crawlers. What is is the best way to create a thread-safe queue to contain unique URLs?

EDIT:
Is there a better solution in .Net 4.5?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Classes in .Net 4.5 for writing a multi-thread C# crawler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086408/classes-in-net-4-5-for-writing-a-multi-thread-c-sharp-crawler)

Comment: OK! So I go there and post a question, few people vote for closing because it's not in ONE area. I come here and post it in ONE area, now you say it's a duplicate! I think whatever I do, some people want to try to close questions. It's easier than answering, right?!

Comment: You should consider deleting your old question that covers multiple areas. That way, this one won't be closed as a duplicate of the other question :)

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I didn't know I can delete a question :D Thanks. Funny, I've spent so much time on SO :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) and use the default scheduler which uses ThreadPool.

---

OK, this is a **minimal** implementation which queues 30 URLs at a time:

```
    public static void WebCrawl(Func<string> getNextUrlToCrawl, // returns a URL or null if no more URLs 
        Action<string> crawlUrl, // action to crawl the URL 
        int pauseInMilli // if all threads engaged, waits for n milliseconds
        )
    {
        const int maxQueueLength = 50;
        string currentUrl = null;
        int queueLength = 0;

        while ((currentUrl = getNextUrlToCrawl()) != null)
        {
            string temp = currentUrl;
            if (queueLength < maxQueueLength)
            {
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        Interlocked.Increment(ref queueLength);
                        crawlUrl(temp);
                    }
                    ).ContinueWith((t) => 
                    {
                        if(t.IsFaulted)
                            Console.WriteLine(t.Exception.ToString());
                        else
                            Console.WriteLine("Successfully done!");
                        Interlocked.Decrement(ref queueLength);
                    }
                    );
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.Sleep(pauseInMilli);
            }
        }
    }
```

Dummy usage:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int i = 0;
        WebCrawl(() => (i = r.Next()) % 100 == 0 ? null : ("Some URL: " + i.ToString()),
            (url) => Console.WriteLine(url),
            500);

        Console.Read();

    }
```

Comment: What about the new .Net 4.5? Is there a better solution in .Net 4.5? And could you please post a sample?

Comment: @AlirezaNoori 4.5 is not officially out yet so how does that help you? I am not aware of any new classes that can help although `async` and `wait` keywords will help.

Comment: I'm developing this app for my research. So it's not a problem. I have used `async` coding in Windows 8 but do you think using `async` is better than multithreading?

Comment: @AlirezaNoori for doing a web crawler, you *should* really use async rather than multithreading as the majority of your time will be spent waiting for web pages. However, the async (certainly prior to 4.5) can be a bit complex to write, so whether the additional complexity is worth it depends on a lot of factors, including whether monopolising a lot of threads is a problem. it's a complex question and worth doing a lot of research into to understand fully.

Comment: I can easily use .Net 4.5 so I guess I can use `async`. Thanks. I'm going to give it a try.

Comment: One question though! I want to run more than one download at a time. I thought about it but I think that multi-threading would be better. Am I wrong? Could you post a little snippet in that case? Thanks

Comment: @AlirezaNoori Frans probably means creating multiple threads rather than using ThreadPool. My answer is short but I think it is the only answer that deals with your question. ConcurrentQueue does not address the threading and parallel running, only synchronisation.

Comment: If possible, could you please post a little snippet? (algorithm is fine too) I'm a little confused of what you're trying to tell, EXACTLY.

Comment: @AlirezaNoori OK you need to give me a few hours. Felan beram code bazanam!

Comment: @AlirezaNoori OK, please have a look.

Comment: Thanks. Now I got what you were saying. But I think I'll use a combination of your solution and ohadsc's solution. I'll set this one as the answer though.

Answer (score 2):

[ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) is indeed the framework's thread-safe queue implementation. But since you're likely to use it in a [producer-consumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem) scenario, the class you're really after may be the infinitely useful [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx).

Comment: Could you please post a very quick sample? Thanks

Comment: Go to the link I gave for BlockingCollection. At the bottom you'll find a simple usage example.

Answer (score 1):

Would `System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<T>` fit the bill?

Comment: Thanks. Is there a better solution in .Net 4.5? And could you please post a simple sample?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue.

You can safely queue and dequeue from multiple threads.

Answer (score 1):

Look at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue.  If you need to wait, you could use System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection